# Inner Product-Norm Inequality

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I am doing some work and reached an inequality where I think I should be able to go further but I am not sure how. I have a Hilbert space of functions on a set $X$. What I have: 
$$\forall x, y \in X, \langle f, g(x,\cdot)-g(y,\cdot) \rangle \leq || g(x,\cdot) -g(y,\cdot)|| $$ where the norm is induced by the inner product. Is there anything I can say about the norm of f?

Answer (score 0):

No, because $f$ can be orthogonal to $g$, then inner product between $f$ and $g$ doesn't tell you anything about the norm(length) of $f$

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, I realized my question wasn’t specific enough. It you’d have the time to take a look at it again I would greatly appreciate

Comment: I am a bit confused, if you take $g(x) - g(y)$, I guess it's a real number perhaps, then the inner product between a function $f$ and a number don't add up?

Comment: sorry, my mistake! I fixed it now.

Comment: Now I think it depends on $g$, for example, let $h(x,y,\cdot) = g(x,\cdot) - g(y,\cdot)$, $h$ can be a unit basis for the space, then $\lVert{h}\rVert$ will be $1$, so we know $\lVert{f}\rVert \leq 1$. It really depends on whether $h$ can cover all "directions", otherwise, $f \perp h$ is always possible, then we can get nothing from the inequality.